# ¿Lleva tilde "Ya te contaré qué/que tal"?

Tags: acentuación, preguntas

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de escribirlo?

> Ya te contaré **qué** tal.

o

> Ya te contaré **que** tal.

Desde mi punto de vista no es una pregunta ni directa ni indirecta y no debería llevar tilde, y tampoco es exclamación.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sí la lleva. Es un pronombre interrogativo.

> Ya te contaré **qué** tal estoy.
>
> "Ya te contaré **cómo** estoy.

Sustituye a una subordinada sustantiva donde explicarías cómo estás, y actúa como nexo entre las dos proposiciones.

Es un "te contaré cómo", así que tiene una clara función interrogativa, aunque no sea una pregunta. Denota información pendiente de especificar.

Ahora bien, la segunda frase podría existir. En ese caso sería un pronombre relativo, que sólo hace de enlace:

> Ya te contaré que tal o cual cosa es...

Comment: ¿Si dices que la segunda podría existir quiere decir que ambas son correctas?

Comment: La segunda podría ser correcta, pero "forzando mucho" la gramática. Es muy rebuscada. Mejor con tilde.

Answer (score -1):

En realidad, está mal redactado, debería ser: Ya te contaré, ¿ qué tal, estoy?.
Tampoco es: Ya te contaré cómo estoy.

La forma correcta es: Ya te contaré, ¿ cómo estoy ?.

Se referencia a pregunta futura de otra persona, preguntando ¿ qué tal estás ? o ¿ cómo estás?

Comment: Eso no tiene sentido.

Comment: La verdad es que he tratado de entenderlo, y tienes razón: ningún sentido.